# Under what conditions can lua_close raise a Segmentation Fault error?

Tags: c, lua

I'm talking about the Lua-C API. A call to `lua_close(lua_State *)` results in a segmentation fault, even if the state is valid. How do I know the state is valid? Because I've used it correctly up to that point.

I'd post the source but it's too long and I'm not sure it would be helpful. It simply throws a segmentation fault error at me and I have no clue why. The Lua stack is empty before the call. Can somebody help me?

Comment: This is a good use case for a binary search for failure strategy. Comment out everything between the call to `lua_open()` (or `lua_newstate()`) and `lua_close()`. The result should not crash. Now put half the code back. Try for a crash. Continue the binary search until you've narrowed the failure down.

Comment: An "is it plugged in?" question: are you certain that you haven't accidentally included more than one instance of the Lua VM in your application? This is easy to do by static linking, and is always a bad idea. If you did, then passing a `lua_State` obtained from one VM to the other is extremely likely to eventually lead to a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The Lua C API should never result in a segmentation fault. If the segfault happens when calling `lua_close`, the most probable reason is that some userdata with custom `__gc` metamethods are failing. From the documentation of `lua_close`:

> Destroys all objects in the given Lua state (calling the corresponding garbage-collection metamethods, if any)

The best way to determine what is the reason for these segfaults is run `gdb` and get a backtrace when it happens. If you compile your library with debug symbols, you should get exactly to the place that causes errors.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not working on any userdata. I'll try gdb once more and report back.

Comment: +1 for advice to get a C-side stack backtrace for the event. Hopefully Develoop will do that and post it along with some details of the platform.

Answer (score 0):

You say that the Lua stack is empty before the call. But is the function to be called on the stack? It should be, even if you call `lua_call(L,0,0)`. Try also rebuilding Lua with API assertions on. It may give you a better error message.

Comment: Whoops, I meant lua_close, not lua_call. Sorry!

Comment: In that case, perhaps you're closing a Lua thread instead of its parent state?

Comment: @Develoop: If it's really `lua_close`, then please edit your question and correct it.